# Wix Installer - Getting data from a Property

Tags: wix

I am using Wix to make an installer and I was wondering how I indirectly get a property's value.

Like if I have a Property WIXUI_INSTALLDIR that is preset with the INSTALLFOLDER value

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```

and this Property then is changed through a a Dialog from user input and I after that would want to get what the user changed the path to, how do I get the "value" out of WIXUI_INSTALLDIR ?

I would like to send this value (a string I suppose) to either the registry or a custom action.
If I try [WIXUI_INSTALLDIR] I get a warning for illegal indirection if used with a custom action and if I try to send it to registry it just becomes "[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" as a string.

EDIT:

My problem is when also using my own made up properties like this:

Property Id="MyOwnProperty" Value="Hello There"

and let's say a Dialogue changes the value of MyOwnProperty, how do I the access the new Value ? Like sending [MyOwnProperty] to a CustomAction as parameter will only get "[MyOwnProperty]" as a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the value of the Property (or Directory) that `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` references. In this case, use `[INSTALLFOLDER]` in the formatted field where you'd like the value.

Comment: It works for just [INSTALLFOLDER] (because it's "premade" by MSI ?) but if I use another Property I made myself I just get the property name (or a warning for illegal indirection using the brackets).

Comment: `INSTALLFOLDER` is not a "premade" Property or Directory. That's one of your own making.